# How to put object in a HashMap in js?

Tags: javascript

I create Simple `HashMap` like this , but When I put an `object` into this map as a `value`, I can't call `object's function` when I get it from map , I find that the `object` was convert to `string` by `toString` function. So what should I do to put the `object itself` rather than a string into map?

```
var g_itemMap =
{
    put : function(key,value){this[key] = value},
    get : function(key){return this[key]},
    contains : function(key){return this.get(key) == null?false:true},
    remove : function(key){delete this[key]}
}
```

I put the object like this:

```
g_itemMap.put(1, object);
```

And get it:

```
var object = g_itemMap.get(1);
```

When I call it's function , it went wrong:

```
object.somefunction();
```

alert can display object:

```
[object BitmapItem]
```

Comment: Where are you putting the object in this code?

Comment: You sure you didn't accidentally put the object in as a key, rather than as a value? Javascript automatically coerces object property names to strings, but it doesn't do anything like that for values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks like working for me.
You can try this;

```
var g_itemMap =
{
    put : function(key,value){this[key] = value},
    get : function(key){return this[key]},
    contains : function(key){return this.get(key) == null?false:true},
    remove : function(key){delete this[key]}
}

var object =
{
    objectfunction: function(){
        console.log('objectfunction called')
    }
}


g_itemMap.put(1, object);
var o = g_itemMap.get(1);
o.objectfunction();
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/hCH8k/

Comment: perhaps my object has some mistakes

Comment: My method is corret.ALL of your code is corret.I delete my object when I use a revert function :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var HashMap = new Object();
HashMap[Key1] = Obj1;
HashMap[Key2] = Obj2;

function get(k)
{
    console.log(HashMap[k]);
}
```

or simply you can use

```
var HashMap = {"Key1":"value1","Key2":"value2"}
function get(k)
{
   console.log(HashMap[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I try

```
var object = { a: function() { alert('b'); } };
var g_itemMap =
{
    put : function(key,value){this[key] = value},
    get : function(key){return this[key]},
    contains : function(key){return this.get(key) == null?false:true},
    remove : function(key){delete this[key]}
}
g_itemMap.put(1, object);
var object2 = g_itemMap.get(1);
object2.a();
```

does alert('b'), which looks correct, to me... :-)